# Error in classifying a variable in parallel for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

In the following code `M1` is a 4d matrix. The error message I receive upon running this code is :

> The variable `this_volume` in a parfor cannot be classified.

From what I understand I am just using the variable as a sliced input and output variable at the same time since I am assigning values to some of it's elements. I am not sure if the two extra for loops after the `parfor` are the cause of the problem. I will be grateful for any suggestions.

```
tic

fill_thresh = 12;

for a_fill = 1:size_M1(4)

    this_volume = M1(:,:,:,a_fill);
    this_volume_copy = this_volume;
    parfor b_fill = 1:size_M1(3)        
       fill_factor = zeros(size_M1(1),size_M1(2));
       for c_fill = 1+2:size_M1(1)-2
            for d_fill = 1+2:size_M1(2)-2                
            fill_factor(c_fill,d_fill) = sum(sum(this_volume_copy(c_fill-2:c_fill+2,d_fill-2:d_fill+2,b_fill )));
                if fill_factor(c_fill,d_fill ) > fill_thresh
                    this_volume(c_fill,d_fill,b_fill ) = 1;
                end
            end
        end        
    toc
    end
    M1(:,:,:,a_fill) = this_volume;
    toc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, this_volume is a sliced variable, but matlab does not recognize this because you are wrapping it in some advanced indexing and looping. Typical technique is to use a temporary variable which directly represents a slice:

```
this_volume = M1(:,:,:,a_fill);
this_volume_copy = this_volume;
parfor b_fill = 1:size_M1(3)        
   fill_factor = zeros(size_M1(1),size_M1(2));
   %get the full slice of this_volume
   helper=this_volume(:,:,b_fill );
   for c_fill = 1+2:size_M1(1)-2
        for d_fill = 1+2:size_M1(2)-2
            fill_factor(c_fill,d_fill) = sum(sum(this_volume_copy(c_fill-2:c_fill+2,d_fill-2:d_fill+2,b_fill )));
            if fill_factor(c_fill,d_fill ) > fill_thresh
                helper(c_fill,d_fill) = 1;
            end
        end
   end
   %write back the full slice
   this_volume(:,:,b_fill )=helper;
end
M1(:,:,:,a_fill) = this_volume;
```